# Unity Session Login

Tags: session, unity-game-engine

I have a login validation where the users will enter their identity card number in unity. In the database, the identity card number is linked to several information. What I want to do is to create a session in the login page where the identity card number will be stored in a string or object and it can be retrieved in another page to call out for the information in the database. However, I have been looking around for solutions that would be able to work on the unity engine but unable to find any. Would be great is anyone can help me with this, thanks!

Comment: does the "other page" mean, you want to access the id card number in different scenes?

Comment: Yes. I do mean the different scenes instead of pages

Answer (score 1):

Few options to access variables across multiple scenes:

- Use static variables, they keep values between scenes : (basic example) http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/41891/static-variables-between-scenes.html
- Look up singletons : http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton (bit complex example, there are simpler ones in unity forums.. Looks like that Toolbox global variable is similar : http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Toolbox )
- (Simple solution) Save&Load values with PlayerPrefs : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html
- Set your script as DontDestroyOnLoad, so it doesnt get deleted when going to another scene : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html (but be careful when entering the same scene, your object gets instantiated again if you dont check it)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Static variables worked for me!